# Multiprocessing and shared multiprocessing manager lists for parsing large file

Tags: multiprocessing, python-2.6, pyparsing

I am trying to parse a huge file (approx 23 MB) using the code below, wherein I populate a multiprocessing.manager.list with all the lines read from the file . In the target routine (parse_line) for each process, I pop a line and parse it to create a defaultdict object with certain parsed attributes and finally push each of these objects into another multiprocessing.manager.list.

```
class parser(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.manager = mp.Manager()
    self.in_list = self.manager.list()
    self.out_list = self.manager.list()
    self.dict_list,self.lines, self.pcap_text = [],[],[]
    self.last_timestamp = [[(999999,0)]*32]*2
    self.num = Word(nums)
    self.word = Word(alphas)
    self.open_brace = Suppress(Literal("["))
    self.close_brace = Suppress(Literal("]"))
    self.colon = Literal(":")
    self.stime = Combine(OneOrMore(self.num + self.colon) + self.num + Literal(".") + self.num)
    self.date = OneOrMore(self.word) + self.num + self.stime
    self.is_cavium = self.open_brace + (Suppress(self.word)) + self.close_brace
    self.oct_id = self.open_brace + Suppress(self.word) + Suppress(Literal("=")) \
            + self.num + self.close_brace
    self.core_id = self.open_brace + Suppress(self.word) + Suppress(Literal("#")) \
            + self.num + self.close_brace
    self.ppm_id = self.open_brace + self.num + self.close_brace
    self.oct_ts = self.open_brace + self.num + self.close_brace
    self.dump = Suppress(Word(hexnums) + Literal(":")) + OneOrMore(Word(hexnums))
    self.opening = Suppress(self.date) + Optional(self.is_cavium.setResultsName("cavium")) \
            + self.oct_id.setResultsName("octeon").setParseAction(lambda toks:int(toks[0])) \
            + self.core_id.setResultsName("core").setParseAction(lambda toks:int(toks[0])) \
            + Optional(self.ppm_id.setResultsName("ppm").setParseAction(lambda toks:int(toks[0])) \
            + self.oct_ts.setResultsName("timestamp").setParseAction(lambda toks:int(toks[0]))) \
            + Optional(self.dump.setResultsName("pcap"))

def parse_file(self, filepath):
    self.filepath = filepath
    with open(self.filepath,'r') as f:
        self.lines = f.readlines()
        for lineno,line in enumerate(self.lines):
            self.in_list.append((lineno,line))
        processes = [mp.Process(target=self.parse_line) for i in range(mp.cpu_count())]
        [process.start() for process in processes]
        [process.join() for process in processes]

    while self.in_list:
        (lineno, len) = self.in_list.pop()
        print mp.current_process().name, "start"
        dic = defaultdict(int)
        result = self.opening.parseString(line)
        self.pcap_text.append("".join(result.pcap))
        if result.timestamp or result.ppm:
            dic['oct'], dic['core'], dic['ppm'], dic['timestamp'] = result[0:4]
            self.last_timestamp[result.octeon][result.core] = (result.ppm,result.timestamp)
        else:
            dic['oct'], dic['core'] = result[0:2]
            dic['ppm'] = (self.last_timestamp[result.octeon][result.core])[0]
            dic['ts'] = (self.last_timestamp[result.octeon][result.core])[1]
        dic['line'] = lineno
        self.out_list.append(dic)
```

However this entire process takes approximately 3 minutes to complete.

My question is, if there is a better way to make this faster ?

I am using pyparsing module to parse each line, if it makes any difference.

PS: Made changes in the routine Paul McGuire's advice

Answer (score 2):

Not a big performance issue, but learn to iterate over files directly, instead of using readlines(). In place of this code:

```
    self.lines = f.readlines()
    for lineno,line in enumerate(self.lines):
        self.in_list.append((lineno,line))
```

You can write:

```
    self.in_list = list(enumerate(f))
```

A hidden performance killer is using `while self.in_list: (lineno,line) = list.pop()`. Each call to pop removes the 0'th element from the list. Unfortunately, Python's lists are implemented as arrays. To remove the 0'th element, the 1..n-1'th elements have to be moved up one slot in the array. You don't *really* have to destroy `self.in_list` as you go, just iterate over it:

```
for lineno, line in self.in_list:
    <Do something with line and line no. Parse each line and push into out_list>
```

If you are thinking that consuming self.in_list as you go is a memory-saving measure, then you can avoid the array-shifting inefficiency of Python lists by using a deque instead (from Python's provided collections module). deque's are implemented internally as linked lists, so that pushing or popping to and from either end is very fast, but indexed access is slow.  To use a deque, replace the line:

```
    self.in_list = list(enumerate(f))
```

with:

```
    self.in_list = deque(enumerate(f))
```

Then replace the call in your code `self.in_list.pop()` with `self.in_list.popleft()`.

But MUCH more likely to be the performance issue is the pyparsing code you are using to process each line. But since you didn't post the parser code, there is not much help we can provide there.

To get an idea about where the time is going, try leaving all your code, and then comment out the `<Do something with line and line no. Parse each line and push into out_list>` code (you may have to add a `pass` statement for the for loop), and then run against your 23MB file. This will give you a rough idea about how much of your 3 minutes is being spent in reading and iterating over the file, and how much is being spent doing the actual parsing. Then post back in another question when you find where the real performance issues lie.

Comment: The reason I used list was I am initializing self.in_list as a proxy list using the multiprocessing manager module. I need to pop off the elements since multiple processes are accessing this list and reading an element off it. I have updated code with the pyparsing portion. I do realise that is the biggest bottleneck but I was hoping there was a better and more efficient method to read line by line when using multiprocessing.